# Placing a jquery animation on image elements when mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to sort out my images to wobble on mouseover. I have the below that I was testing that on click moves the whole div to the left. However, all i want is on the mouseover of each image, they wobble.

Any help and advice would be sweet!

```
        HTML 

        <div class="top-header"class="page-header">
            <h1>Smile Board</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-lg-12">
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                  <img  class="img-responsive" src="./images/image01.png" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/image02.png" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/image03.png" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/image04.png" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/image05.png" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/image06.png" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/image07.png" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/image08.png" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/image01.png" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/image02.png" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/image03.png" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/image04.png" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
    body {
      font-family: 'Baloo Bhaina', cursive;

    }

    @media (min-width: 1200px)
    .container {
      width: 1170px;
    }


    h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .page-header {
      background-color: #8AFFC1;
      padding-top: 20px;
      width: 1130px;
    }

    .top-header {
      width: 1130px;
      background-color: #8AFFC1;
      padding-top: 20px;
      width: 1290px;
    }

    .sub {
      /*background-color: #EFEC86;*/
      padding-top: 20px;
    }

    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      display: block;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    .thumbnail {
      width: 250px;
      height: 270px;
      overflow: auto;
      /*max-width:calc(150% - 10px);*/

    }

    .row {
      margin-right: 50px;
      margin-left: -15px;
    }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").click(function(){
    $("div").animate({right: '250px'});
  });
});
```

Comment: how do u achieve wobbling? there is mouseover event in javascript

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about using pure CSS and keyframes? If so then see this link that will explain...Using javascript is fine for something like this too, but in my opinion, for something this small, CSS would be fine.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/shake-css-keyframe-animation/

Comment: amazing @Alex Spencer

Answer (score 0):

See below code snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").on('mouseover', function(){
    $("div").animate({height: "300px"});
  });
});
```

```css
body {
      font-family: 'Baloo Bhaina', cursive;

    }

    @media (min-width: 1200px)
    .container {
      width: 1170px;
    }


    h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .page-header {
      background-color: #8AFFC1;
      padding-top: 20px;
      width: 1130px;
    }

    .top-header {
      width: 1130px;
      background-color: #8AFFC1;
      padding-top: 20px;
      width: 1290px;
    }

    .sub {
      /*background-color: #EFEC86;*/
      padding-top: 20px;
    }

    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      display: block;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    .thumbnail {
      width: 250px;
      height: 270px;
      overflow: auto;
      /*max-width:calc(150% - 10px);*/

    }

    .row {
      margin-right: 50px;
      margin-left: -15px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-header"class="page-header">
            <h1>Smile Board</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-lg-12">
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                  <img  class="img-responsive" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTOLu1xsB5p3fYIGSG06rWNOXau_UJRm5Kx7EqDKibwolZq9U_g" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              
            </div>
```